# Integral inequality for continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

How do I show the following inequality?

Let $\Omega = (0,1) \subset R^1$

Let $u(x) \in C^1(\overline \Omega)$ with the property that $\int^b_au(x)dx=0$

Then, there exists a constant $C>0$ such that $||u(x)||_{L^2(\Omega)} \leq C||u'(x)||_{L^2(\Omega)}$

I was able to write  $\int^b_a|u(x)|dx \leq ||u'(x)||_{L^2(\Omega)}||1||_{L^2(\Omega)} = ||u'(x)||_{L^2(\Omega)}(1-0)^{1/2} = ||u'(x)||_{L^2(\Omega)}$ by using Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I could not proceed any further.

I think that I somehow have to use the mean value theorem for integrals to relate $\int^b_a|u(x)|dx$ with $\int^b_a|u(x)|dx$.

Comment: The best constant $C = \frac{1}{\pi^2}$, known as Wirtinger Inequality, see [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/934112/129017) for a weaker bound.

Answer (score 1):

An easy proof: Take $v=u^2$ so that $v'=2uu'$. Therefore the fundamental theorem of calculus gives
$$
u^2(x)\leq \int_0^1 2|u(t)||u'(t)|dt\leq 2 \| u\|_{L^2}\| u'\|_{L^2}.
$$
Integrating over $x$ we get the result with $C=2$.